# Untypical trying to get property of non-object...?

Tags: php, laravel, relationship, laravel-5

I have a problem with Laravel 5. I get a

> trying to get property of non-object

error when I try to access an eloquent property in blade.

But it's not normal because this works fine:

```
{{ dd($item->relation->property) }}
```

While this throws the error:

```
{{ $item->relation->property }}
```

What's going on there? I already tried to clear the cache, I also deleted the compiled views.

### Update 19.01. 14:24 EST

Here's the content of my database (All items in my item-dump):

- http://hastebin.com/onipizebef.pas
- Item dump: http://hastebin.com/fasoyuwefi.coffee

It stops counting at ID22:

```
[2016-01-19 13:17:34] local.INFO: 10  
[2016-01-19 13:17:34] local.INFO: 11  
[2016-01-19 13:17:34] local.INFO: 12  
[2016-01-19 13:17:34] local.INFO: 19  
[2016-01-19 13:17:34] local.INFO: 21  
[2016-01-19 13:17:34] local.INFO: 22  
[2016-01-19 13:17:34] local.ERROR: ErrorException: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/vagrant/Code/Emerald/storage/framework/views/e18baccf6428ca42183f454a47f2cc9156379826.php:22
```

I did Log::info($item->id) before I access any other property of this object.

Comment: What is the value of that property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it! The relation to my item #22 (where the error occoured) was soft-deleted but now I did this and everything works fine again :)

```
$item->relation()->withTrashed()->get()->first()->property
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you perhaps be doing this in a loop, and thus the `dd()` finishes the execution after the first iteration?

Comment: Yes I'm doing this in a loop. A foreach loop. But every Item in the database have that property.

Comment: Could you please post the output of dd($items), that is, the output of the array you're looping over?

Comment: I added these infos in my post.

Answer (score 0):

What is likely happening is when you are using `$item->relation` is your relation is returning an empty value. When a query in Laravel gets nothing from the database, you get a `null` result, of which there is no `->property` to grab.

You can verify this by doing logging your `$item->relation` value, either to some local log file you then tail -f on, or by printing it to the screen with `(new \Illuminate\Support\Debug\Dumper)->dump($item->relation);` within your loop.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand what u're trying to tell me.

Comment: One of your relationships isn't returning any related models.